# tkinter shortcuts impossible to enable

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running out of shortcuts in the program I'm writing, and there is a large subset of them that I'm finding it impossible to enable.
I'm starting to think that it can be OS or desktop related, so I tell you I'm running Fedora Linux, under KDE.

This is the small prog I use to explore my keys problems :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python   
from Tkinter import *    
root = Tk()
text=Text(root)    
text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand = YES)

def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char)

def testfun(a):
    print"test worked, pressed %s: control key %s" % (repr(event.char),str(a))  

text.bind("<Key>", key)
for i in range(10):
    text.bind('<Control-'+str(i)+'>',  lambda event,arg=i:testfun(arg,event))

mainloop()
```

(I dont have problems only with ctrl-number shortcuts, but let's start here).

My problem: Ctrl-6...Ctrl-0 are intercepted, but I cant find a way to make Ctrl-1..Ctrl-5!

The example output for 1..6 is:

1: pressed '1'

2: pressed ''

3: pressed '\x1b'

4: pressed '\x1c'

5: pressed '\x1d'

6: test worked, pressed '\x1e': control key 6

I also tried to binding the shortcuts to root, and also to do a *return 'break'*, but nothing worked.

Do you have any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some fixes to your code which make it work:

First of all, the `key` function should use `keysym` member instead of `char` of `event`:

```
def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.keysym)
```

Then your binding function should use simply the `key` function, no need for that lambda. Also you should bind `<Control-Key-1>`, not `<Control-1>`, (the latter refers to the muse button), so:

```
for i in range(10):
    text.bind('<Control-Key-'+str(i)+'>',  key)
```

and you can erase the line:

```
#text.bind("<Key>", key)
```

You can also bind the lower case letters like so:

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
    text.bind('<Control-Key-'+chr(i)+'>',  key)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I feel hugely embarassed... but I was confused by the fact that all the letter bindings I wrote as <control-a> worked perfectly!!!